# defaultValue not updating on DOM re render in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working on react js, I have a text in that user can enter value,so I have used defaultValue in that. this value an be change by external event also. but if value is modified using external event it is not reflecting in my input box (untill I refresh the page). but I put that value `value` field of input box it is updating. but user can  not edit it. how can I have both functionality means user can update as well other events also.
here is my input box

```
  <input type="text"  defaultValue={this.props.growth}  onBlur={(e) => this.props.growth(e.target.value)}></input>
```

EDIT1:
I added function like vivek said but now text box became un editable

```
constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state ={
           modifedProgramGrowth: this.props.growth
       }
   }
updateGrowthValue(key){
        console.log("value",key)
        this.setState({growth:key})
}

<input type="text"  value={this.state.growth} onChange={(e) => this.updateGrowthValue.bind(e.target.value)} onBlur={(e) => this.props.growth(e.target.value)}></input>
```

Comment: can this.props.growth be the state of this component?

Comment: @VivekN: but in that case I can't make it editable

Comment: why is that so, you can have defaultValue as this.state.growth and onChange you update your state with this.setState and with that react will cause a re render  and your input box will start having the user typed values.

Comment: @VivekN you are talking about controlled components, which don't use `defaultValue` but just `value`

Comment: Make use of a controlled input, so you will be having an onChange handler to update the value when you type and you can also update the state on some event which will also be reflected

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: can you please explain me with example

Comment: @LowCool if you this growth variable being passed from an external component then you also need to pass a function which would be triggered on change and that function would cause a change in the growth value of the parent component thereby causing a re render.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edited question, you need not make use of bind to supply the parameter to the function if you are already using an arrow function. Change to

```
constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state ={
           modifedProgramGrowth: this.props.growth
       }
   }
updateGrowthValue(key){
        console.log("value",key)
        this.setState({growth:key})
}

<input type="text"  value={this.state.growth} onChange={(e) => this.updateGrowthValue(e.target.value)} onBlur={(e) => this.props.growth(e.target.value)}></input>
```

Comment: but in that my value not getting updated by external event..:( this is may be because my constructor initializes only once right?

Answer (score 0):

from shubham's answer to make editable text box and I have added `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` to my code to solve the problem

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
{
        let {growth } =this.state;
       growth = nextProps.growth ;
        this.setState({growth })
}
```